# is_integer() doesn't work with Enum.all?

Tags: elixir

Total Elixir noob here. Here's my question:

When using the `Enum.all?/2` function, we pass a function as the second argument:

```
iex(19)> is_int = &(is_integer(&1))
iex(20)> Enum.all?(list, is_int)
true
```

Why is it, then, that I can't pass `is_integer` directly?

```
iex(21)> Enum.all?(list, is_integer)
** (CompileError) iex:21: undefined function is_integer/0
    (stdlib) lists.erl:1354: :lists.mapfoldl/3
    (stdlib) lists.erl:1355: :lists.mapfoldl/3
```

Is `is_integer` not a function? It looks like that from the error. What is the `mapfoldl` we see there?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to capture this function. Use:

```
Enum.all?(list, &(is_integer(&1))
```

Comment: Wow, that works! Needs a `)` at the end, though. What is this capturing and why is it needed? More importantly, why is it no needed when anonymous functions are assigned to variables?

Comment: Capture operator captures function as a anonymous function. More here: http://elixir-lang.org/docs/stable/elixir/Kernel.SpecialForms.html#&/1.

Comment: `Enum.all?(list, &is_integer/1)`
You can use this form, like more readable and without a lot of `)`.

Answer (score 4):

Elixir is what is called a Lisp-2 language - regular functions (often called named functions) and functions captured as a value (often called anonymous functions) occupy different spaces, are called differently and use different operators.

You create a named function with `def` and `defp`, and you call a named function with parenthesis - e.g. `foo()`.

You convert a named function to an anonymous functions with `&` operator - e.g. `x = &foo/1`.

You create an anonymous function with `fn` and call with `.` preceding the parenthesis - e.g. `foo.()`.

Anonymous functions are values like all other - integer, map, etc, so you can pass them around as all other values. Named functions can only be called or converted to an anonymous function, they can't be directly passed around.

Comment: Whoa! That's very interesting stuff. Thanks for sharing! Some lightweight articles you'd recommend around language theory? :-)

Comment: No problem! Thanks for dropping by! :-)

Answer (score 2):

When you bind an anonymous function to an existing function, these 3 are equal:

```
is_int = fn n -> is_integer(n) end
is_int = &is_integer(&1)
is_int = &is_integer/1
```

The last one is the most concise one, since it only need the function name and arity.

Note, since the function in Kernel module is imported automatically when you start IEx, so the above match is actaully

```
is_int = &Kernel.is_integer/1
```

In this case, after you capture the named function using the capture operator `&`, you can pass it to any function expecting a function as parameter. Or just pass the captured function directly.

```
Enum.all?(list, is_int)
Enum.all?(list, &is_integer/1)
```

Comment: I like the way you explain it

Answer (score 0):

You can use `is_integer` function directly

`Enum.all?(list, fn(i) -> is_integer(i) end)`

This is also working

`Enum.all?(list, &(is_integer(&1)))`

Comment: But that's exactly what happens in the first case I posted. My question is, why doesn't writing `is_integer` work?